# How to output letters letters remaining/used in Hangman C#

Tags: c#

I have created a hangman game in C#. It all works fine, except that I would like it to display which letters are remaining when the user inputs a letter already used. However, it is showing only the chosen letter and not the others which remain.

I have included my full source code below. The section between the // ********** is where I believe the fault lies.

```
    static void Main()
    {

        do
        {
            Console.Title = ("Hangman Game");

            // word bank (for the purposes of this question, only "mario" is used with all other words commented out)
            string[] secretWords = { 
                "mario", /*"sonic", "thelegendofzelda", "donkeykong", "luigi",
                "peach", "link", "laracroft", "bowser", "kratos",
                "playstation", "nintendo", "tetris", "grandtheftauto",
                "finalfantasy", "thelastofus", "ghostoftsushima", "horizonzerodawn",
                "halo", "forza", "crashbandicoot", "worldofwarcraft", "callofduty",
                "fortnite", "animalcrossing", "doom", "metalgearsolid", "minecraft",
                "residentevil", "pacman", "spaceinvaders", "asteroids",
                "streetfighter", "mortalkombat", "supermariokart", "pokemon",
                "bioshock", "tombraider"*/
            };

            // select a random word from the list of secretWords
            Random R = new Random();
            string secretword = secretWords[R.Next(secretWords.Length)];
            List<string> letterGuessed = new List<string>();

            // set the number of lives the player has
            int lives = 9;

            // Playing the game
            Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome To Hangman!");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter to guess for a {0} Letter Word", secretword.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("You Have {0} Lives remaining \n", lives);
            Isletter(secretword, letterGuessed);

            while (lives > 0)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                // advise the player their chosen letter has already been used
                if (letterGuessed.Contains(input))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You Entered Letter [{0}] Already", input); 
                    Console.WriteLine("Try a Different Letter \n");
                    GetAlphabet(input); //
                    continue; //              
                }

                // advise the player they guessed the secret word and won the game
                letterGuessed.Add(input);
                if (IsWord(secretword, letterGuessed))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", secretword.ToCharArray()));
                    Console.WriteLine("You Won! Congratulations!");
                    break;
                }

                // advise the player their chosen letter is correct
                else if (secretword.Contains(input))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Good Entry\n");
                    string letters = Isletter(secretword, letterGuessed);
                    Console.Write(" " + letters + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }

                // advise the player their chosen letter is incorrect
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That Letter Is Not In My Word");
                    lives -= 1;

                    // advise the player how many lives they have remaining
                    Console.WriteLine("You Have {0} Lives Remaining", lives);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                // advise the player they have no lives remaining and lost the game - Game Over
                if (lives == 0)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("You lost! Game Over! \nMy Secret Word is [ {0} ]", secretword);
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("play again? [y or n]");
        } while (Console.ReadLine() != "n");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress the enter key to exit.");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();


        // replace underscores with correct letters in correct positions
        static bool IsWord(string secretword, List<string> letterGuessed)
        {
            bool word = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < secretword.Length; i++)
            {
                string c = Convert.ToString(secretword[i]);
                if (letterGuessed.Contains(c))
                {
                    word = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return word = false;
                }
            }
            return word;
        }
        static string Isletter(string secretword, List<string> letterGuessed)
        {
            string correctletters = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < secretword.Length; i++)
            {
                string c = Convert.ToString(secretword[i]);
                if (letterGuessed.Contains(c))
                {
                    correctletters += c + " ";
                }
                else
                {
                    correctletters += "_ ";
                }
            }
            return correctletters;
        } 
        
        //********************************
        static void GetAlphabet(string letters) //
        {
            List<string> alphabet = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
            {
                char alpha = Convert.ToChar(i + 96);
                alphabet.Add(Convert.ToString(alpha));
            }
            int num = 49;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine("Letters Left are :");
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                if (letters.Contains(letters))
                {
                    alphabet.Remove(letters);
                    num -= 1;
                }
                Console.Write("[" + alphabet[i] + "] ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            //********************************
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Then GetAlphabet needs to use letterGuessed, which is your list of all letters guessed so far, which it doesn't at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should send letterGuessed list to GetAlphabet method like this, GetAlphabet(letterGuessed);

Then I changed that method like:

```
void GetAlphabet(List<string> letterGuessed) //
        {
            List<string> alphabet = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
            {
                char alpha = Convert.ToChar(i + 96);
                alphabet.Add(Convert.ToString(alpha));
            }
            int num = 49;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine("Letters Left are :");
            /*for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                if (letters.Contains(letters))
                {
                    alphabet.Remove(letters);
                    num -= 1;
                }
                Console.Write("[" + alphabet[i] + "] ");
            }*/

            IEnumerable<string> lastArr = alphabet.Except(letterGuessed);
            foreach (var item in lastArr)
            {
                Console.Write("[" + item + "] ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            //********************************
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, That worked... But any idea how I can output a list of which letters were used after the player has won?

Comment: LetterGuessed array hold these, right?. You can print every item in this array after Console.WriteLine("You Won! Congratulations!");

Comment: I tried that already. This was the output...                                                                                                m a r i o
You Won! Congratulations!
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
play again? [y or n]

Comment: Console.WriteLine("You Won! Congratulations!");
foreach (var item in letterGuessed)
{
      Console.Write("[" + item + "] ");
}

Please mark my answer as answer :)